# what is the differents between com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener and android.location.LocationListener?

Tags: android, location, google-location-services

I want to ask about the onLocaticonChange method which is in those two libraries. I can catch the locations from android.location.LocationListener but when I decided to use the onLocationChanged method by google.android.gms.location.LocationListener, the location parameter return null.Here is my build.gradle file :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.1'
```

I don't know what is differents. Can anyone descripe me that ?
Thanks.

Comment: i could be wrong but com.google.android.gms.location   will give you location from google map which wares  near to exact it  required Internet  so when your location is changing it may be usedAnd android.location  will provide location based on  mobile tower which access last  so when your network changes it use

Comment: I create a library for that and I use the the two libraries but I can catch location from android.location.LocationListener. The other one is just working for FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation. Thanks for your response is helpful :) @VishalMokal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener**

This come with google play services. Basically Google play services will be looking for continues location updates for its own use. You will be one more user same location updates will be sent to you.

**android.location.LocationListener**

This basic location listener which you set up for your usage, and the location uapdtes will be sent to you as soon location provider is set up for you as Constraints set(like battery, power, location provider,accuaracy)

Differences

1. com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener will require google
   play services set up, android.location.LocationListener is very
   basic dosent require no play services dependency
2. most of the times com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener faster,and will start quick upadtes as it already set up and location already available.